# Can "agency" in the sense of "self-agency" be plural?

Tags: word-usage

My question pertains to academic writing in fields like philosophy.

Normally "agency" meaning "the capacity, condition, or state of acting or of exerting power" (Merriam-Webster) is an uncountable noun, as in "My agency in this matter is limited. I can't do much to help you."

In academic usage, can it also be plural? Example: "Refugees have many agencies in resisting marginalization," meaning they have many different ways of taking control. Or should it be "Refugees have a great deal of agency." Can anyone find an example of the plural "agencies" in academic writing? I just need to know if it's permissible.

Comment: No. *Refugees have much agency in resisting marginalization.*

Comment: If it’s academic writing, ask your grading/reviewing agency whether *they* will accept it.

Comment: I am the reviewing agency. :-) I don't like to change people's writing if something is odd but permissible. Philosophy writers have a distinct style---they take a lot of liberty with language.

Answer (score 2):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/agency) says that "agency" with this meaning is uncountable:

[image]

If you put it in the plural it will be understood as:

> businesses that represent one group of people when dealing with another group

or

> government organizations.

You don't want that. If your emphasis is on the plurality of ***ways***, you may want to say:

> Refugees have/find many ***ways to exert agency/ways of exerting agency*** in resisting marginalization.

Google provides a few academic instances of the expression [***ways of exerting agency***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ways%20of%20exerting%20agency%22&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk02iv0bE4hiiOS5yZSkU1dIADxNsqA%3A1622813520257&ei=UCu6YNyLD8rRgwe_jYSwDQ&oq=%22ways%20of%20exerting%20agency%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnULaqAVjttQFgp70BaAFwAngAgAHkAYgBzQOSAQUzLjAuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjc86S7i_7wAhXK6OAKHb8GAdYQ4dUDCA4&uact=5) or [***ways to exert agency***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ways%20to%20exert%20agency%22&safe=strict&sxsrf=ALeKk03fHaO5mBNHPZwkMuH9jMgREDmtxA%3A1622813477947&ei=JSu6YM-rOcTbgweN_b24Cg&oq=%22ways%20to%20exert%20agency%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABOgcIIxCwAxAnOgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnUL80WNU8YPdFaAFwAngAgAGdAogBhQSSAQUyLjEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiP0o6ni_7wAhXE7eAKHY1-D6cQ4dUDCA4&uact=5).

Comment: I'm looking for examples in academic publications that show that "agencies" is permitted, even if we think it's awkward.

Comment: Good luck with that!